# grant all on Owner.table_name to APPS,ABC;

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi
I was trying to execute 
grant all on Owner.table_name to APPS,ABC;
but it is giving an error that grant privileges not provided.
Please let me know how can i get and what is the reason.

Comment: The grant statement and the error message might be helpful.

Comment: ... and your current user and the owner of `table_name` too.

Answer (score 0):

You need Owner to: `GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE TO You;`

You will see that you do not have it by running:

```
select * from system_privilege_map
where name like '%PRIV%';
```